# Is this step in a formal proof syntactically valid

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to prove $P \vee \neg Q \rightarrow R, P \vdash R$, where $\vdash$ means that $R$ is true given that $P \vee \neg Q \rightarrow R$ and $P$ are true (i.e. $R$ is a valid inference from the premises $P \vee \neg Q \rightarrow R$ and $P$)

As an attempt for a formal proof, I came up with the ff:

1. $P \vee \neg Q \rightarrow R$ : Given
2. $P$ : Given
3. $P \vee \neg Q$ : Using the Addition Inference Rule on (2)
4. $R$ : Using Modus Ponens on (1,2)

What I am not sure with my proof is the third step, whereby I used the addition rule on $P$ in order to obtain $P \vee \neg Q$. However, I am not sure if this is allowed since strictly speaking, the Addition Inference Rule states that given $P$, we can rewrite it as $P \vee Q$ for any $Q$. However, in this case, I applied to $P$ the $\vee$ operator on a  propositional form with negation (i.e. $\neg Q$) ...

Is this is not valid, is there a method for "adding" propositional forms with negations to $P$?

Comment: A formal proof is a purely syntactical object where you can infer statements from other statements in accordance to formally defined inference rules. This means that whether what you have here is a formal proof or not depends on exactly the formal inference system you are working with. For some systems everything you do here is in accordance to their inference rules, and so it would be considered a formal proof in that system. For other systems this is not so. In short: not knowing what exact formal system you work with, we cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly correct. *Disjunction Introduction* or *Addition*, states that for **any** propositions $X,Y$ if you have $\Omega \vdash X$ then you have $\Omega \vdash X\lor Y$. Remember that if $Q$ is a proposition so is $\neg Q$, so the rule applies.